# iOS - running service in background

Tags: ios, service, background, network-programming

I'm developing an app for iOS7 that is always receiving data from an UDP socket.
It does not fit any of the Apple's background modes so i suppose i can only have the service running for 10minutes.

Is it possible to, after the 10min, send an alert to the user that allows the service to run for more 10min or so?

Are there any other tricks to allow the service to run for more time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps can works in background, there are some Background modes which you can find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) but take care because if you use one of these modes for continuing working in background and you don´t use its mode, your app will be rejected by Apple.

For example if you set your app with backgroundmode voiceip and you don´t use voiceip, your app will be rejected by Apple

Comment: i've seen that link already, and my app does not fit any of those modes. i was asking if there was any other way to keep the service running in background

Comment: There isn´t. At least if you want to upload your app to App Store